# What are jQuery best practices regarding Ajax convenience methods and error handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's suppose, for an example, that I want to partly clone Gmail's interface with jQuery Ajax and implement periodic auto-saving as well as sending. And in particular, let us suppose that I care about error handling, expecting network and other errors, and instead of just being optimistic I want sensible handling of different errors.

If I use the "low-level" feature of $.ajax() then it's clear how to specify an error callback, but the convenience methods of $.get(), $.post(), and .load() do not allow an error callback to be specified.

What are the best practices for pessimistic error handling? Is it by registering a .ajaxError() with certain wrapped sets, or an introspection-style global error handler in $.ajaxSetup()? What would the relevant portions of code look like to initiate an autosave so that a "could not autosave" type warning is displayed if an attempted autosave fails, and perhaps a message that is customized to the type of error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The common practice is to use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to specify a generic callback handler for errors during the non-`$.ajax` functions. E.g.

```
function init() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: handleXhrError
    });
}

function handleXhrError(xhr, errorType, exceptionThrown) {
    // ...
}
```

Inside the `handleXhrError` you can display either a modal window or some notification bar like Gmail does, or replace the entire `document`, depending on the functional requirements. You can take action based on the response body as obtained by `xhr.responseText` and/or the [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) from `xhr.status`. The values of the response body and status are controllable from the server side on. Those should provide enough information about the problem and which error action to take. The `errorType` will equal to `'timeout'` when a timeout has occurred (i.e. network problem).